# Tables do not show in the Assistant for mobile

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm building and currently testing my first Assistant app with DialogFlow and a custom WebHook, and I'm planning to use table cards in devices that support `actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT`.

I've tried to create a response with a `simpleResponse` followed by a simple `tableCard`, but although I can see the table in the simulator, I can't see it in any physical device that has output support (sorry, I don't have a smart display yet so I can't test it there ;)

I thought that maybe I had made a mistake, so I tried answering with the following sample code that I copied from [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#table_card). Unfortunately, I got the same results.

This is the sample code I tried:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Simple Response"
            }
          },
          {
            "tableCard": {
              "rows": [
                {
                  "cells": [
                    {
                      "text": "row 1 item 1"
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "row 1 item 2"
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "row 1 item 3"
                    }
                  ],
                  "dividerAfter": true
                },
                {
                  "cells": [
                    {
                      "text": "row 2 item 1"
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "row 2 item 2"
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "row 2 item 3"
                    }
                  ],
                  "dividerAfter": true
                }
              ],
              "columnProperties": [
                {
                  "header": "header 1"
                },
                {
                  "header": "header 2"
                },
                {
                  "header": "header 3"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
    }
  }
}
```

I did some research because later on I thought that maybe they're supposed to be hidden under certain circumstances, or they are not supported yet (because I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556178/1121392) that they were added recently), so the question is: does someone know why they fail to show?

This is a screenshot I've taken of the simulator:

[image: Screenshot showing the table in the simulator]

And this is the same response seen in an iOS device with the latest Assistant (v1.3.3408):

[image: Screenshot showing that no table shows in an iOS device]

I forgot to say that I also tried with this sample code in a Firebase-hosted webhook, and it also failed to show in my physical devices: https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.table.html

Answer (score 1):

I just found [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#table_card) the following notice which answers my original question:

> **Note:** The table card feature is currently in developer preview. During the developer preview, you can test responses with table cards in the Action Console simulator, but users will not see the cards in the production version.

It seems like we'll have to wait before we can use them :)